# Firefox saves comment text in textContent inside of style element

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom, frontend

I have following div

```
<div id="test"><style type="text/css"><!-- comment --></style><span>text</span></div>
```

I need to retrieve it's visible text content, I am using `textContent` property like this:

```
document.getElementById("text").textContent
```

It works fine in Chrome, but, suddenly, Firefox returns `<!-- comment -->text`. I know, I can fix it by using one more temporary div (`document.createElement`), but, maybe, there is a better way?

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e28m64tf/

**UPD:**

It seems that this code returns wrong result in Chrome too. My bad.

Comment: It's returning <!-- comment -->text in Chrome as well in that jsfiddle.

Comment: can you move the style section out of your div? or better, put it into a css file? or are u doing component thing so you have to make it structure like that?

Comment: @spaceman Yes, it seems you're right. I changed my question, thank you.

Comment: @innek No, actually, I can't. The thing is that I am using `textContent` functionality to clean up content of `contenteditable` div. And user can put anything in it, so I need generic solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried `.innerText` instead? (You might need to go research browser compatibility.)

Comment: @CBroe Hmm... actually, it seems, it works in this example. Actually, I've tried it earlier, and it didn't work, maybe I confused it with something else. Thanks, I will look at it closer!

Answer (score 1):

You will get the same result in Google Chrome too. To fix this problem you can try this:

```js
alert(
  document.getElementById("test").
  textContent.
  replace(/<!--(.*?)-->/gm, '')
);
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <style type="text/css"><!-- comment --></style>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's possible to trim comments content using regexp, but I'm not sure it will work for more compex cases. The thing is that I use this functionality to clean content of `contenteditable` div, so I need generic solution.